# Include files in a command line with Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, include

When running ruby scripts as such

```
ruby some-script.rb
```

How would I include a file (e.g. configuration file) in it dynamically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you have found, the -r option is your friend.  It also works with IRB:

```
irb -ropen-uri
```

Will do the same as `require 'open-uri'`

FWIW, the most common thing I need to include via the command line is rubygems.  And since newer versions of ruby come with gems built in I don't want to edit the file, but include it for testing. Luckily the folks who created gems added a little alias sugar.

You can do the following:

```
ruby -rubygems myscript.rb
```

Instead of the ugly:

```
ruby -rrubygems myscript.rb
```

OK, so it is one character, but thought it was extra polish to make me happier.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I found it. It's the -r command line entry.

Answer (score 2):

```
 -r <library_name>
```

This causes Ruby to load the library using require.

It is useful when used in conjunction with `-n` or `-p`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
require 'some_ruby_file'
```

in some-script.rb. It will load some_ruby_file.rb.

Comment: Thanks, but not what I asked. I was looking for a way to do it in the command line i.e. without modifying the scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Before you call `require "somefile.rb"` you must navigate to the folder that the file is located or you must provide the full path. In example: `require "~/Documents/Somefolder/somefile.rb"`